# plot many lines

Tags: gnuplot

how can I plot for each master a line in function of nombre and temps. At the end I want three lines one for each master. my file data is :

```
score;master;nombre;temps
-60;pastel1;7;100
30;pastel2;0;100
100;pastel3;0;100
-60;pastel1;3;220
30;pastel2;4;220
100;pastel3;0;220
-60;pastel1;0;440
30;pastel2;4;440
100;pastel3;3;440
-60;pastel1;0;445
30;pastel2;3;445
100;pastel3;4;445
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
plot '<grep pastel1 test.dat' u 3:4 w lines,\
     '<grep pastel2 test.dat' u 3:4 w lines,\
     '<grep pastel3 test.dat' u 3:4 w lines
```

Or shorthand using iteration:

```
plot for [i=1:3] sprintf("<grep pastel%d test.dat",i) u 3:4 w lines
```